# Move directory on restart

Tags: mount, ssh, fstab

I'm using Ubuntu Server 20.04, and have access to a *remote* server via SSH.

I need more room in the root FS, and so have made a copy of the `/var` directory on another partition. I've then added to my `/etc/fstab` to make it mount the new `/dev/sdX2` over the old `/var`.

All is well... `df -h /var` indicates that it's using the newly mounted version.

However, I now can't remove the original one to free up the space that I so badly need. If I run `mount --bind / /mnt/root`, and then try to do anything, like `mv /mnt/root/var /mnt/root/var.old`, I get: `mv: cannot move 'var' to 'var.old': Device or resource busy`.

As this is only really accessible through SSH, I can't get in to single user mode.

So, the only other thing I can think of is to have a script that will move the original `/var` directory to `/var.old`, and then, once I can see everything is working correctly, remove it once and for all.

The main issue is that this script will need to load **before** `fstab` *or* anything hooks in to `var`, and I'm not even sure if that's possible?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is past EOL, and we no longer answer questions about it here. Consider re-partitioning and re-installing to remove some of your constraints.

Comment: I'm trying to upgrade, that's why I need the space. Let's say I'm on 20.04. Nothing I've remarked upon has changed in the release cycles since.

Answer (score 1):

Your mount command is not the good one. You must call the disk drive device, not the root symbol ie

```
sudo mount /dev/sdZX /mnt/root
sudo mv /mnt/root/var /mnt/root/var.old
sudo umount /mnt/root
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `mv` or `rm` the folder `/mnt/root/var` since `/var` is used as mountpoint for your new partition. Instead, `mv` it's contents:

```
mkdir /var.old
mount --bind / /mnt/root
mv /mnt/root/var/"*" /mnt/root/var.old/
umount /mnt/root
```

After checking that everything works fine you can remove `/var.old`

```
rm -r /var.old
```